# MongoDB - Returning only matching Array from Object

Tags: mongodb

i have the following document in a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : 101,
    "students" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "john",            
            "age" : 10,
            "city":'CA'
        },
        {
            "name" : "danial",            
            "age" : 15,
            "city":'KA'
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : 102,
    "students" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "adam",            
            "age" : 20,
            "city":'NY'
        },
        {
            "name" : "johnson",            
            "age" : 12,
            "city":'CA'
        }
    ]
}
```

And i fire the following query:

```
db.data.find({'students.city':'CA'})
```

This returns me "students" objects from both the documents, as one instance matches the filter ("city"; 'CA') in both.

However, i desire to only get the matching array in the result. That is, i want the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : 101,
    "students" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "john",            
            "age" : 10,
            "city":'CA'
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : 102,
    "students" : [        
        {
            "name" : "johnson",            
            "age" : 12,
            "city":'CA'
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** in your projection:

```
> db.data.find({'students.city':'CA'},{ students:{ $elemMatch:{'city':'CA'} }})
{ "_id" : 101, "students" : [ { "name" : "john", "age" : 10, "city" : "CA" } ] }
{ "_id" : 102, "students" : [ { "name" : "johnson", "age" : 12, "city" : "CA" } ] }
```

Btw: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an aggregation operation.

Here you have the documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

And a similar question:
[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Nope, that's plainly wrong. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35408883/1296707).

Comment: yep. you are right. after confirming again. it's better your way. 

Correct me if I'm wrong:


I said to use aggregate because I thought you cannot return multiple elements of an array matching your criteria using a find() operation. but since it's different documents and only 1 matching element per document.your way it's the right one.

Comment: I haven't checked, but I think it could be possible to use an "$or" in the projection...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg i tried to use $or inside the $elemMatch to return multiple elements, but it was not working.